# Azure Policy Cosmos DB Disable Synapse Link

Tags: azure-policy

I am looking to put an azure policy in place to deny the ability to enable synapse link on cosmosDB.

There are no suitable built in policies.
I have tried creating my own under if Microsoft.Synapse/privateLinkHubs is true then deny creation. but it still allows creation.

I suspect as it may be enabled at cosmosdb level it may not be possible to deny this, but would be great to get confirmation.

Thanks :)

Comment: Azure Policies are designed to control the creation and configuration of Azure resources and services. However, they have limitations, and there may be certain actions, like enabling Synapse Link on Cosmos DB, that are not directly controllable through Azure Policies.

Answer (score 1):

@cavematt You can create a custom policy to deny the ability to enable synapse link on cosmosDB.

**Policy Definition:**
[image]

[image]